# override checkout index controller

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, plugin, preference

```
I would like to override only one line in checkout/index/index controller.
```

do I need to use preference or plugin or observer?

```
if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && !$checkoutHelper->isAllowedGuestCheckout($quote)) {

            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Guest checkout is disabled.'));

            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');

        }
```

to

```
if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && !$checkoutHelper->isAllowedGuestCheckout($quote)) {

            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Guest checkout is disabled.'));

            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('customer/account/login');

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preference like this in your custom module:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for=Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index\Index" 
             type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Index" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Preference to override the controller.